# Php resolve blocks of text to make query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write mysql query for search which is based on the following search.
Search Query string: "(foo and bar) or (blah1 and blah2)"

User will input the query string as mentioned above, it might be a single block or more than one block.

What i want to do is split the string into block of brackets resolve them individually and then combine it with `OR` or `AND` statement.

So my end query would look like

```
Select 
  * 
from 
  table 
where 
  (field like 'foo%' AND field like 'bar%') OR 
  (field like 'blah1%' AND field like 'blah2%')
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues.

You need to explode out the query string into individual elements, and then explode those out to individual values, then build up the query.

You also need to make the input safe, either by escaping it or using prepared statement.

Using mysqli to use prepared statements something like this:-

```
$query_string = strtolower("(foo and bar) or (blah1 and blah2)");

$queries_sets = explode(' or ', $query_string);

$query_set = array();
$fields = array();

foreach($queries_sets AS $query_set_key=>$query_set_value)
{
    $query_line = explode(' and ', trim($query_set_value, '()'));
    if (count($query_line) == 2)
    {
        $query_set[] = "(field like ? AND field like ?)";
        $fields[] = $query_line[0].'%';
        $fields[] = $query_line[1].'%';
    }
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".implode(' OR ', $query_set));
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $fields);
```